# How to add a cell reference in this excel case?

Tags: excel, reference, cell

If I have a function like this

```
='S\My\Question\Is\[Cell Reference.xlxs]Sheet2'!B1.
```

How can I reference a cell in these marks `[ ]`?

I need the cell reference because I have many Excel files in that S-drive location and I have a list of the files which I'm trying to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("'S\My\Question\Is[" & A1 & ".xlxs]Sheet2'!B1")
```

But as a note, INDIRECT is Volatile and as such will return an error if the Workbook is not open when Excel recalculates anything.

Comment: Thank you, this worked but I'm looking a way to do that without opening the worbkook where I'm looking for data. Is there any way to do that without opening workbok, example with VBA?

Comment: Even vba will need to open the work book to get the data.